# Masonry.js two column layout with "hoisted" different sized blocks

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-masonry, masonry

### Background

I am using Masonry.js only because I believe this will be the simplest way to achieve this effect. It may not even be the right tool for the job.

### What I want to accomplish

I am building a two column layout that contains 2 different sized "blocks". One of them is a big block, 60% width and 200px height. The small block is 40% width and 100px height.

What I am trying to achieve is the blocks to flow into a layout where at any given time there is a big block (on the left or right) and 2 small blocks to the right or left of a big block.

If the HTML is not ordered like that, I want it to "hoist" the small block up to fill in any gap that might be present.

My current **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/gavzrhgg/1/)** conveys this rather well (I hope!).

### My code

My HTML looks like this

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">7 (should be under 4)</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">8 (should be above 9)</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">9 (should be under 8)</div>
    <div class="grid-item">10</div>
</div>
```

where `.grid-item { width: 60%; height: 200px; }`
and  `.item2 { width: 40%; height: 100px; }`

My Masonry.js plugin init code looks like this:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 1
});
```

---

### The issue

So ultimately the issue is that the small block is not being hoisted up to fill in the gap (to the left of #5, the big block).

### More background

Because these `grid-item`'s will be dynamic, I cannot count on them flowing in in any particular order, that is why I have turned to using Masonry. They will eventually be blog posts, which the user can specify whether they want it to be a big or small block and then they will be sorted by date order & of course size (which this post is about).

Answer (score 0):

If you want sorting, simple logic can do that. Combine with DOM manipulation, and you get:

```js
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];

for(var i = 0; i < grid.children.length - 1; i++) { // iterate over children except last
  var find = [2, grid.children[i].classList.contains('item2') ? 1 : 2]; /* depending on
    current item type, looking for items [2, 1 or 2] in that order. */
  for(var f  = 0, j = i + 1; f < 2 && j < grid.children.length; j++) { /* iterate over
      all children starting after i, or until found 2 items */
    var child = grid.children[j];
    var item = child.classList.contains('item2') ? 2 : 1; // do we have 1 or 2?
    if(find[f] == item) { // is it the one we're looking for?
      if(j > i + 1) // is it ahead of where we want it to be?
        grid.insertBefore(child, grid.children[i + 1]); // Yes, so relocate...

      i++; // advance i, we moved ahead
      f++; // advance f, we found a match
      j = i; // reset j (will be j++ in the for)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">7 (should be under 4)</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">8 (should be above 9)</div>
    <div class="grid-item item2">9 (should be under 8)</div>
    <div class="grid-item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and sorry for the delayed response). This works for just ordering them, but I also need to take styling into account. With the code you provided and my basic styling, it doesn't place item 5 next to 4 & 7, which is where i was hoping Masonry would help out. [See my fiddle with your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/1413vjzf/)